# Why my website's animation won't show up on github pages ? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a portifolio website and deployed it to github pages. The problem is : when I am running the page locally it works normally but when I look at the link on github pages it won't show the animation background I made.

This is my entire project code :

```js
import "./style.css"
import * as THREE from 'three';

// Setup

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),
});

renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.position.setZ(30);
camera.position.setX(-3);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

// tetrahedro
const tetra = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
const tetrahedro = new THREE.Mesh(tetra,new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial(0xffffff));
scene.add(tetrahedro);
// Lights

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.set(5, 5, 5);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(pointLight, ambientLight);

// Helpers

// const lightHelper = new THREE.PointLightHelper(pointLight)
// const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 50);
// scene.add(lightHelper, gridHelper)

// const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

function addStar() {
  const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 24, 24);
  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
  const star = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  const [x, y, z] = Array(3)
    .fill()
    .map(() => THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(100));

  star.position.set(x, y, z);
  scene.add(star);
}

Array(200).fill().forEach(addStar);

// Background

const blacktexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('black-screen.jpg');
scene.background = blacktexture;

// Avatar


// Moon

const moonTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('moon.jpg');


const moon = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 32, 32),
  new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    map: moonTexture
  })
);

scene.add(moon);

moon.position.z = 30;
moon.position.setX(-10);

tetrahedro.position.z =60;
tetrahedro.position.setX(-15);

// Scroll Animation

function moveCamera() {
  const t = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  moon.rotation.x += 0.05;
  moon.rotation.y += 0.075;
  moon.rotation.z += 0.05;

  tetrahedro.rotation.x += 0.05;
  tetrahedro.rotation.y += 0.075;
  tetrahedro.rotation.z += 0.05;

  camera.position.z = t * -0.01;
  camera.position.x = t * -0.0005;
  camera.rotation.y = t * -0.0005;
}

document.body.onscroll = moveCamera;
moveCamera();

// Animation Loop

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  tetrahedro.rotation.x +=0.005;

  moon.rotation.x += 0.005;

  //controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

```css
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/jmk3xov.css");

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


:root {
  --dark-bg: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.95);
  --spacing: 350px;

  font-family: brandon-grotesque, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}


main {
  width: 100vw;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.925);
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 120px 0px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
}

h1, h2, h3, blockquote {
  font-family: elevon, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}



  header {
    background: var(--dark-bg);
    grid-column: 2 / span 5;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: var(--spacing);
  }

  section {
    grid-column: 2 / 8;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: var(--dark-bg);
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: var(--spacing);
  }

  blockquote {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    grid-column: 2 / span 9;
    margin-bottom: var(--spacing);
    border-radius: 5;
  }

  blockquote p {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(43, 42, 42);
    font-size: 4rem;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 5;
  }

  .left {
    grid-column: 6 / 12;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Luis's Portifolio</title>
    <style>   
      /* Style the Sticky icons on web page */   
      .stickyicon-list {   
      position: absolute;   
      top: 400px;
      left: 10px;
      transform: translateY(-50%);             
      }          
      .stickyicon-list a {   
      display: block;   
      text-align: center;   
      padding:left;   
      transition: all 0.5s ease;   
      color: white;   
      font-size: 70px;

      }         
      /* HOver affect on sticky social media icons */   
      .stickyicon-list a:hover {   
      color: rgb(83, 76, 5);   
      width:10px;   
      }   
         
      /* Now we have to design each icon of social media */         
      .facebook {   
      background: #3b5998;   
      color: white;  
      }         
    
      .linkedin {   
      background: #0e76a8;   
      color: white;   
      }           
      .instagram {   
      background: #3f729b;   
      color: white;   
      }
      #porti{
        background-color: black;
        color:white;
      }
      #arduino{
        background-color: black;
        color:whitesmoke;
      }
      .button{
        background-color:rgb(56, 81, 82);
        color:white;
        padding-right: 10px;
        border-radius: 25;
      }
      </style>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>   

    <main>

      <header>
        <h1>Luis Filipe</h1>
        <p> ‍♂️ Welcome to my Portifolio! </p>
        <div class="stickyicon-list">  
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/FelipeAraujods1/" target="_blank" class="facebook"
          >   
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>   
      </a> 
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/luisfaraujo1999/" target="_blank" class="instagram">   
            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>   
        </a>    
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/luis-filipe-de-ara%C3%B9jo-06337717b/" target="_blank" class="linkedin">   
              <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>   
        </a> 
         
        </div>
      </header>


      <blockquote id="jobyoulove">
        <p>Choose a job you love, and you will never have to work a day in your life.</p>
      </blockquote>

      <section>
        <h2> About myself</h2>
        <p>
          I am a Brasilian Electrical engineering student who loves to code.
        </p>

        <p>
          I got into programming as soon as I first met Python in a class at UFV.
          Ever since I have been working in some small and big projects including mainly machine learning 
          and data analyses. In the begining of 2021 though I was talked into a web developing course by a friend
          and I fell in love for the topic. Now I am starting my web developing career and will take any challenges
          you may have to offer me. 
        </p>

      </section>

      <section class="light">
        <h2>‍ Projects</h2>

        <p>
          <ul>
            <li>My first ever web developing project was the building and styling of this web page.</li>
             <a href="https://github.com/Doquey/Portifolio" target="_blank">

              <button type="button" class="button">
              <span class="button__icon"> <ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon> </span>
            </button>
          </a>
            <li>A program that intagrates Python  and Arduino  in order to take data from a working glow motor.</li>
            <a href="https://github.com/Doquey/Arduino-Python" target="_blank">
              <button type="button" class="button">
              <span class="button__icon"><ion-icon name="logo-github"></ion-icon></span>
            </button>
          </a>
          </ul>
        </p>

        <h2> Accomplishments</h2>

        <p>
          <ul>
            <li> Passing grade of 85% on Python  for research hosted by harvardX</li>
          </ul>
        </p>

      </section>

      <blockquote>
        <p>The best way out is always through! <br>-Robert Frost</p>
      </blockquote>

      <section class="left">
        <h2>✈️ Work History</h2>

        <h3>diElétrica</h3>
        <p>
          As a freshman I worked in a project called "diElétrica" on my university. The main purpose of this project
          is to simulate the day to day of an Electrical engineering company. There I worked as a manager administrator.
          2018-2019
        </p>
        <h3>Skywards UfVoa</h3>
          In the begining of this year I applied to this another project within my university. The main goal
          of the project is to create a radiocontrolled airplane to go competing in the end of the year.
          I am still active in the project as head of the Eletronic and instrumentation sector.
        <p>
   
        </p>

      </section>

      <blockquote id="work">
        <p>Let's work together? <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/luis-filipe-de-ara%C3%B9jo-06337717b/" target="_blank" class="linkedin">   
          <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>  </a></p>
      </blockquote>


    </main>
    
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>




  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>






  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried lots of things such as : inserting a "/" to the "main.js" script, I have tried to deploy my code in two different ways as well :
1)creating manually the "dist" folder and moving all the images and js and html code in there
2) running the npm run build command to create the dist folder automatically.

Comment: Are there any errors appearing in your developer tools? Can you share them here?

Comment: main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
favicon.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: These but they keep changing and I am running the same exact code haha

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the github pages site?

Comment: https://doquey.github.io/lasttry/  Forgot to put in with the post, mb

Comment: Here is a Discussion with similar issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382774/how-do-you-fix-broken-pathing-when-pushing-to-github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Not Sure how GitHub pages are configed however they probably have cross-scripting disabled since it is a major security risk. When disabled third-party dependencies won't work often. so if your animation depends on any script outside the server then it won't work it could also be that the file structure changed when being uploaded.

Comment: it does show these errors :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/lasttry/favicon.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/lasttry/favicon.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: ok, So the issue is probably Xscripting. You need to download those resources and serve them from a file in your web project. you could type wget and then the url to those files in your terminal syntax: wget http://lastry/favicon/whatEverUrlIs.file to download the dependencies hope that helps

Comment: Also Some time entering the url you used in your html to call those dependencies into your browser bar will also download the file if you are not comfortable with the terminal yet

Comment: I will surely try that sir, thank you for your help!!

Comment: I solved that problem for the vite icon but now it's saying my main.js file is missing : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()  .... main.js

Comment: Ok, now I got these : GET https://doquey.github.io/dist/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
favicon.ico:1 GET https://doquey.github.io/favicon.ico 404 and I ran the exact same code. Sorry the flood of information, I am really eager to solve this. Spent all day yesterday trying.

Comment: so I believe you are telling me that you downloaded the icons from a third party successfully. and they worked on the page but now The Js file that was working before no longer works. 404 means the resource cant to be found some times check your file paths if your using a short path like "./thisISTheFile" try the full /var/www/HTML/thisISTheFile vice versa. post the code you are working with ill check in and see if I can further help.

Answer (score -1):

this is wrong.
`<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>`
try `<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried it but still same problem. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () but now it's https://doquey.github.io/Porttifolio/dist/main.js in the end of this message.

Comment: the issues seem to be a directory path issue try loading with a url instead of the file path I.E https:YourDomainName/main.js. the directory structure on the server is different than the one on your working machine.  I'm unfamiliar with Github pages structure.

Comment: The tip you gave solved the url problem. The page has come up with another thing though haha, now it says :     style.css:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: This Has To do With A setting in the Server Config You Are Going To Have To ask Github pages I'm Not Sure. check there forums. if Any of this was usefull please note it im trying to get rep up

Comment: I'll reach out there. Your tip about the url think worked very well, so yeah you were very helpfull, how do I note it ?