# How do you fix broken pathing when pushing to github?

Tags: html, css, github-pages

Hey I have a quick question. When I pushed my repository to git it no longer connects my html documents to my style sheet or corresponding images. When I open the html files from vscode in chrome it works perfectly, but as soon as I pushed it to github and deployed it, it only shows the html. Is there a way I need to change my pathing so that it will work on pages?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/style.css">
```

or

```
<img id="frogicon"src="/Images/frogiconpure.jpg" alt="frog icon">
```

Comment: why don't you close your tags, is your web host Linux based, that is case sensitive in file path

Comment: @rioV8 Do you mean closing the link and img tags? and the hosting is through github pages. I've already checked the case sensitivity and I'm planning on going through and standardizing the names of my files and folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah this is a frustrating issue for me as well. The solution I use relies on running a local NodeJS server during development, which has code to redirect requests starting with `/${projectName}/`. I then set up all of my URLs for internal assets to work in the GitHub Pages context.

I have a template repo in GitHub that I use as a base for my new projects, which uses this approach. Here's a link to the appropriate section of the Readme: [GitHub Pages](https://github.com/Cipscis/base-project#github-pages)

This approach works without any extra bits on GitHub Pages, but for it to work with local development it relies on two parts:

1. A local server that redirects URLs starting with `/${projectName}/` to the root-relative paths needed for local development ([server code](https://github.com/Cipscis/base-project/blob/main/server/server.js)).
2. An environment variable configuring the name of my project (the [`.env`](https://github.com/Cipscis/base-project#env-1) file in my setup)

If running a local NodeJS server isn't something that works for your project, there may be other ways in your environment to do the same sort of redirection. And if you're only worried about the single project, then you could hard-code the name of your project instead of having it configured as an environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm fairly early into my web development journey so a lot of this is above my head right now. I just wanted to use Github Pages to be able to link to other live versions of what I'm working on locally. I've only learned how to use HTML and CSS, so when I'm more comfortable with JS or Node.js, I'll try to work this out. Is there an easier way to deploy than github pages?

Comment: There are other options, but I like GitHub Pages because I find it pretty simple to use. It's nice, free hosting for static websites :)

Another thing I used to do to solve this problem, which also worked but I found was more of a pain to set up, was to create a symbolic link in order to emulate the structure that GitHub Pages would use.

I'm not sure what OS you're on, but I'm using Windows 10 and I would create these by opening a command prompt in the root of my project (I found I needed it to have administrator privileges too) and running `mklink /D MyProjectName .`

Comment: So for setting up the node.js server. Where would I create that file for the script?  And then what do I need to modify within the code? Would that be the project names? Thank you so much btw, I was feeling really confident with my HTML and CSS and then I hit this and I felt like I was back at square one.

Comment: Yeah I understand that frustration when you only want to do HTML and CSS. The server file can go anywhere, I like putting it in a folder called "server" in the root of my project. The project name is the name of your repo on GitHub - the bit in the GitHub Pages URL. In my base project, I run the server via the comment `node server/server.js` (I've actually got it set up through the `npm start` script, but in the end that's the line it runs to start the server). You'll need Node installed, and a package.json file with [express](https://expressjs.com/) as a dependency in order to run the server.

Comment: Okay, I installed node.js and I created a package.json file with express. I also created a folder and file within my repository called server. Do I need to move that folder to my repository?

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to give detailed instructions in StackOverflow comments due to the character limit. Hopefully you might find it useful to clone my base project I linked to and see how it works, I've tried to make that various parts of it clear in the readme file. The place where you put the server file in your project doesn't matter so much, but you will need to make sure it's running, and then you'll access your project via localhost on whatever port you've told Express to run the server on (this is something I configure in a `.env` file, I typically use port 8080 as a default).

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you so much again!